# iPad PDF rotation problem

Tags: ipad, pdf, pdf-generation, rotation, rotatetransform

I am having an issue regarding rotation of a pdf document in ipad. Have tried a lot using the following code, please have a look at it:

```
-(void) MyDrawPDFPageInRect:(CGContextRef)context :(CGPDFPageRef)page :(CGPDFBox)box :(CGRect)rect :(int)rotation :(bool)preserveAspectRatio
   {

        CGAffineTransform m;
    m = CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform (page, box, rect, rotation, preserveAspectRatio);
    CGContextSaveGState (context);
        CGContextConcatCTM (context, m);
        CGRect pageframe = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect (page, box);
        CGContextClipToRect (context,pageframe);
        CGContextDrawPDFPage (context, page);
        CGContextRestoreGState (context);
}
```

The code above is rotating the pdf but pdf size goes on diminishing with further rotation.
I think there is some problem in my code. So please give me some solution as i need to submit this app ASAP.

Regards
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CGRect mediaBox = CGPDFPageGetCropBox(page, kCGPDFCropBox)

The above thing needs to be rotated.

Thanks anyways...